# Upgraded to 16.04 -- now have Flaky HTTP Connections

Tags: networking, 16.04

I have a laptop - Clevo W670RZQ - i7-6700HQ 2.60GHz Processor, Intel HM170, Dual Band Wireless -AC 3165 and Bluetooth Module, IEEE 802.11a/b/g/n, 433 Mbps, M.2 2230.

Before, on 15.10, the laptop was perfect in terms of web browsing (and pretty much everything else).

After upgrading, my HTTP connections are really bad. When loading a web page, it will get stuck trying to make a connection (to get an ad, or a css file, or whatever). Or sometimes it will not make a connection at all and just sit and the loading indicator will just spin. I'm using Chrome 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit), but it seems to happen with Firefox as well.

If I do a Ping while this is happening, it works just fine. It just seems to be HTTP (although admittedly, I haven't tried much besides pinging when this happens).

I don't know much about Linux networking at all (using Linux for software development), so I'm at a total loss here.

Can someone give me pointers as to where to start to figure out what's going on? I'm close to just wiping and going back to 15.10, but thought I could spend a little while trying to fix the issue first.

The only thing I've tried so far is to turn off power management on the wireless card - didn't make any difference.